# Enable ssh in jboss admin console

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, middleware

Is any one can step down how to configure standlone.xml file to enable the SSH in jboss 7.1.1 admin console.

I tried using the below link but it does not work.

[Accessing JBoss Management Console over Https in JBossAS 7.1.2](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2461)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a keystore with the following keytool command:

> ```
> keytool -genkeypair -alias serverkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 7360 -keystore server.keystore -keypass mypassword -storepass mypassword -dname "cn=Server Administrator,o=Acme,c=GB"
> ```

2. Copy the server.keystore under server's configuration folder
3. Next, include in your ManagementRealm configuration a server-identities definition which references our keystore as follows:

> ```
> <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
>     <authentication>
>         <local default-user="$local"/>
>         <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
>     </authentication>
>     <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
>         <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
>     </authorization>
>     <server-identities>
>         <ssl>
>             <keystore path="server.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="mypassword" alias="serverkey"/>
>         </ssl>
>     </server-identities>
> </security-realm>
> ```

4. Replace the http socket binding with an https socket binding:

> ```
> <management-interfaces>
>     <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm" http-upgrade-enabled="true">
>        <!-- <socket-binding http="management-http"/> -->
>               <socket-binding https="management-https"/>
>     </http-interface>
> </management-interfaces>
> ```

5. Check the port binding: the management-https binding will already exist in default socket binding groups, defaulting to 9443. If not, add it with:

> ```
> <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
> ```

Comment: Thank you very mush @Varsha. The issue was with the jboss server version.Before i used jboss 7.1.1 and now i use 7.1.2 (EAP Edition) .

To download the Jboss 7.1.2 use the below link steps. blog.kaltepoth.de/posts/2013/02/12/building-jboss-as7.html .

To enable ssh in admin console your configurations worked fine.